# Javascript - Convert string with comments to object

Tags: javascript, string, object

how can i change following string to Object?

---

```
"password: {
  minLength: 8, // some comments
  maxLength: 24,
  strong: (value) => /.*[^0-9]+.*[0-9]+.*|.*[0-9]+.*[^0-9]+.*/.test(value),
},"
```

Comment: Where do you get this string from? You can use `eval`, but that is only safe if you control this string, and not a user.

Answer (score 0):

If -- and only if -- this string is under your control, and not that of a user of your application, you can use `eval`. Note that some changes are needed, as the string contents do not represent valid JavaScript, it seems to be an object with a `password` property, but the surrounding braces are missing.

So here is how it could work:

```js
let input = `password: {
  minLength: 8, // some comments
  maxLength: 24,
  strong: (value) => /.*[^0-9]+.*[0-9]+.*|.*[0-9]+.*[^0-9]+.*/.test(value),
},`;

// Add braces to make it a valid object literal, and
// add parentheses to make it into an expression:
let result = eval(`({${input}})`);
console.log(result);
```

NB: You cannot use `JSON.parse` here, as this string is not valid JSON, nor does JSON support function syntax.

If however, the string is user-provided, then you should not use `eval`. You could even question whether you should support parsing such user input, as it could execute code you don't really want it to execute.